# Mixed check-in policy in Gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

we actually search for the possibility to change a check-in behavior in Gerrit.

What we want is:

- On Master allow only check-ins which can be fast-forwarded
- On Check-in itself, do not do a fast-forward, always force a merge (--no-ff).

Actually I found a way to change the master branch to be on "always merge" while other branches uses the configurarion from the project setting.
I did this with the rules file.

```
submit_type(merge_always) :-
        gerrit:change_branch(B), regex_matches('refs/heads/master.*', B),
        !.
submit_type(T) :- gerrit:project_default_submit_type(T).
```

But how I could check if the changeset is potentially fast-forwardable?

Another solution could be that I change refs/head/master.* to fast_forward_only but then I anyhow have to modify the submit button that --no-ff will be appended. But I don't know how.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think you can "force-merge" when there are no other changes but yours - this is a basic behavior of git. When there are no other changes on the remote branch, your only option is to fast-forward.

Comment: Why this should not be possible? You can do an empty commit with --no-ff

Comment: What is the benefit of forcing an empty merge? For me it just makes it harder to follow the path of changes done. (To your question: I am not familiar with a way to configure this behavior at the branch-level in Gerrit)